# canvas.drawwindow method for IE 9

Tags: html, canvas

I have to capture a screen shot in IE 9 for that i am using canvas .drawwindow()        which          is not showing any result.
    Please suggest me some method.
    canvas.drawwindow() is working fine in Firefox as it is extended method in Firefox
    Can i have the same implementation for Internet Explorer 9.

Answer (score 1):

`context.drawWindow` is unfortunately a proprietary method in Firefox, only available in extensions:

> It is not allowed in normal HTML pages

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Graphics/Drawing_graphics_with_canvas)

This is not available in IE or other browsers.

You can optionally use [Html2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) which can get you close to give you a snapshot of the page. [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) restrictions applies.